# Isn't posible to use one queryset inside another?

Tags: django

model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...

class CarInstance(models.Model):
    car =  models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

Isn't posible to use one queryset inside another?
Like:

```
data1 = Car.objects.filter(id__in = [1,3,6])
data2 = CarInstance.objects.filter(car = data1)
```

I need to use both queryset objects in the future. And Car can have a few CarInstance objects. I think isn't possible to unite in one queryset like `data2__data1`.

And cycle like:

```
car_list = []
for i in data1:
  car_list.append(i.id)
data2 = CarInstance.objects.filter(car__in = car_list)
```

looks ineffective. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to do this

```
data2 = CarInstance.objects.filter(car__id__in = [1,3,6])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get ids from data1 objects use:

```
data1_id = Car.objects.filter(id__in = [1,3,6]).values_list('id', flat=True)
```